# Set different keyboard resize mode per page

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I use the following line in AndroidManifest.xml file and it took effect, but it changes the keyboard resize mode for total app, how to dynamically set the different mode for different pages?

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this value at runtime.

In `Activity` or `Dialog`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

Comment: Sorry, I  want to do it in ionic project